# How do I use row wise values in case statement in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to define values for my column with the help of case statement. But this case statement should take values from a table which is dynamic.

For example, the below query

```
SELECT 
    id,
    CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(state),  'tamil') THEN 'tamil'
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(state),  'andhra') THEN 'telugu' ELSE 'others' END AS language
    FROM 
table_name
```

gives the output as

```
id    language
001   tamil 
002   telugu
003   tamil 
004   others
```

But if I have the state information in a separate source and is also dynamic(states can be added and removed) like below,

```
table_name : state_table

SCHEMA:
state   STRING

PREVIEW:
state
tamil nadu
andhra pradesh
kerala
```

how do I replicate the same output as the above in this case. Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Where does the language come from?

Comment: @GordonLinoff language is a derived column based on values in the column "state".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `state_table` really has the language, you can use `join`:

```
SELECT t.*, s.language
FROM table_name t JOIN
     state_table s
     ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(t.state),  s.state)
```

Comment: no, the "state_table" doesn't have any other information apart from state names. thats why I was trying with case. (language is a derived column based on values in the column "state")

Comment: @ThivagarMoorthy . . . Then the `state` table really has no relevance for the query.